# Problema ao captar tipo de string com router AltoRouter

Tags: php, regex

Estou usando o AltoRouter para fazer a chamada de página do meu projeto, e no doc dele fala que para usar "Match Types" customizados é só adicionar

`$router->addMatchTypes(array('cId' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9](?:_[0-9]++)?'));`

Porém, tentei usando esta regra: `|^[\pL\s]+$|u`, que valida letras (incluindo acentos) e espaços e não funcionou, vi que as regras padrões que estão na classe são assim:

```
protected $matchTypes = array(
        'i'  => '[0-9]++',
        'a'  => '[0-9A-Za-z]++',
        'h'  => '[0-9A-Fa-f]++',
        '*'  => '.+?',
        '**' => '.++',
        ''   => '[^/\.]++',
    );
```

Também tentei inserir a regra já na classe e também não obtive sucesso, entendo muito pouco de Regex, mas parece que as regras-padrão estão escritas de uma forma diferente  e "enxuta", seguindo este padrão, como posso validar somente letras(incluindo com acentos), espaços e números?

Answer (score 1):

A expressão está correta, exceto pelo alternador `|` que está inserido na primeira posição dela. Remova-o e deixe a expressão da seguinte forma:

```
^[\pL\s]+$|u
```

Você pode verificar ela funcionando no [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/b1dYLg/1)

Caso queira "enxugar" a expressão e deixá-la mais legível, podes utilizar:

```
^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s]+$
```

Você pode verificar ela funcionando no [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YGBqRT/1)